# Oracle 10gr2: prevent any dates that fall on a Sunday?

Tags: oracle, constraints

Is it possible to use a CHECK constraint to prevent any date that falls on a Sunday?  I don't want to use a trigger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a check constraint can check that the day of the week is not Sunday.  Here's an example:

```
create table date_test (entry_date date);

alter table date_test add constraint day_is_not_sunday
      check ( to_char(entry_date,'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH') not like 'SUNDAY%');
```

--There are blank spaces to the right of SUNDAY so like or rtrim is needed to match the string.

```
insert into date_test values(to_date('2008-10-12','YYYY-MM-DD')); --Sunday
insert into date_test values(to_date('2008-10-11','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into date_test values(to_date('2008-10-10','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into date_test values(to_date('2008-10-09','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into date_test values(to_date('2008-10-08','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into date_test values(to_date('2008-10-07','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into date_test values(to_date('2008-10-06','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

When you try to insert a date that is on a Sunday, it will say:
`ORA-02290: check constraint (SYS.DAY_IS_NOT_SUNDAY) violated`

Comment: Are there concerns about localisation when using this method? Does to_char(..., 'DAY') always return English day names?

Comment: Good point, I updated the constraint to set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE= ENGLISH.  Apparently TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') has a similar issue here because the date that is coded as 1 varies across regions.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you use `'fmDAY'` for the format, you can change the comparison to simple equality `= 'SUNDAY'`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the actual constraint, but you can use the function:

```
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D');
```

to get the day of the week as an integer, then do a small check on it